# How (from explorer) do you "open with" a program that's not listed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In XP the "open with" sub-context-menu had an item "choose program".  In 7 this has been replaced by "choose default program".  What's the equivalent to the old option?

[image: context menu option in win7]

I'm not interested in changing the default, I just want to open my pdf in the GIMP (to post a question about the contents elsewhere on stackexchange in fact).

Comment: So you were afraid to click it and see what happens next?

Comment: @Moab not at all, it seemed pointless to click something that did pretty much the opposite of what I was looking to do.

Comment: But it didn't do that, it gave you options instead. Sometimes you have to be curious.

Comment: @Moab, you're right, believing windows' lies is futile. Yes I do regard a deliberate change from the old, correct, description to the new, incorrect one as lying.  It's on a par, logically, with clicking file|open to get a blank document.

Comment: Oh a Windows hater, its not lying, it misrepresentation, I just usually say Windows sucks, and leave at that.

Comment: @Moab not a hater, but I'm not keen on the direction changes have been taking recently.  IME misrepresentation==lying unless there's a plausible chance it was accidental, which I don't accept here.  Anyway, hopefully I've learnt to look in unexpected places next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve by opening at gimp once

To achieve it do the following

1)choose the pdf right click

2)navigate to open with choose default program

3)ensure you unchecked the **always use the selected program to open this kind of file**

4)open it using gimp

5)thereafter gimp would be listed under open with

[image]

hope it helps

Comment: So they've *renamed* the option but not actualy changed it?! I would never have thought to look under "choose default" for "do something other than default" or "choose non-default".  I've been away from windows too long (or maybe not long enough).  I'll accept in a few minutes when I can.

Comment: @ChrisH they just renamed and altered the functionality friend,right now they provided one more additional facility for selecting default programs,notably the default program appears on top  of open with